# how to publish (fake) odometry i.e, getting odometry without robot?

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, localilzation, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use the odometry data over rgbdslam package. I do not have any robots. So, Is there any possiblity to publish a fake odometry (for the known distance)?

Thanks in advance for the reply.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43177/how-to-publish-(fake)-odometry-i.e,-getting-odometry-without-robot?/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One way is to write your own node that will publish fake data. Tutorial for odometry publisher can be found at:

> http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom

It requires some changes, but will give you possibility to publish automaticly whatever you need, without any user input. Other option is to use turtlesim and move fake robot around with a teleop (using keyboard or joystick). It will publish odometry for you, so there is no need to wirte any additional code, but you need to keep interacting with robot to generate change in published position.

---

Originally posted by [kszonek](https://answers.ros.org/users/2959/kszonek/) with karma: 459 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps you can save data from a simulation (turtlebot) using ROSbag and play this data back in your own simulation?

---

Originally posted by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) with karma: 2573 on 2012-09-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-09-06**:
any links or packages, how to run the turtlebot in simulation...

**Comment by [davinci](https://answers.ros.org/users/3014/davinci/) on 2012-09-20**:
Sorry I meant the turtlesim not the turtlebot (should also be possible btw)
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes